# Rotativa + MvcMailer Acess is Denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rotativa

Please help me I've got this problem recently:
I was trying to generate pdf from view but I've got some issues on server side after publishing

Exception: Access is denied
    Controller: Example
    Action: ExampleView

```
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver.Convert(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches, String html)
   at Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.CallTheDriver(ControllerContext context)
   at Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.BuildPdf(ControllerContext context)
   at Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

I have really no idea what is going on... Rotativa version 1.6.1 locally its working but on server I get this error...
 Controller:

```
namespace ZarzadzaniePortalem.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ExampleController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult ExampleView()
        {

            return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("ExampleToPrint")
            {
                FileName = "ExampleToPrint.pdf"
            };
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExampleToPrint()
        {
           /* some viewbags */

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope your issue was resolved. If not, then let me post one of the solutions that worked.

- [Using ViewAsPdf](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/issues/57) is one. Instead of using the `ActionAsPdf()` you can use the `ViewAsPdf()`.